# Check external package in Autotools

Tags: c++, gnu, autotools

I would like to check the presence of the google [sparsehash](https://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/) package in my C++ program with the Autotools.

Here is a minimal `configure.ac`:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([myprog], [1.0], [adress@email.com])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([main.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign -Wall -Werror])

AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([google/sparse_hash_map])

AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

I run `autoreconf -vfi`, then `./configure`, and I get:

```
checking google/sparse_hash_map usability... no
checking google/sparse_hash_map presence... no
checking for google/sparse_hash_map... no
```

However, I can check the presence of `/usr/include/google/sparse_hash_map`, a C++ file, which is a thin wrapper around `/usr/include/google/sparsehash/sparsehashtable.h`. Moreover, the tiny code:

```
#include <google/sparse_hash_map>
int main() {return 1;}
```

compiles and executes fine using `g++ test.cpp`.

Any suggestion for a newbie?

Comment: Although this was answered already, I'll just add that you should always check `config.log` for the details on why it failed, including the source code for the test program that failed, and the actual compiler error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AC_CHECK_HEADER` macro is using the `C` compiler by default. You can change the current language using: `AC_LANG([C++])` or: `AC_LANG_PUSH([C++]) / AC_LANG_POP` - as described in the (single-page) [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Language-Choice). e.g.,

```
...
AC_LANG([C++])
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([google/sparse_hash_map])
# still in C++ 'mode'
```

or:

```
...
AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([google/sparse_hash_map])
AC_LANG_POP([C++])
# restored previous language 'mode'
```